# Prove partial binomial sum is order of magnitude lower than full sum.

Tags: probability, summation, binomial-coefficients, poisson-process

I have the following binomial summation:

$$S(\alpha) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{S_{X_0}^{-1}(\alpha)} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j$$

Where $X_0$ is binomial with parameters $n$ and $0.5$ and $S_{X_0}^{-1}(\alpha)$ is its inverse survival function.

I need to prove that this summation is an order of magnitude lower than $(2+p)^n$ for any $0<\alpha <1$ and $p>0$. It has to have a bound like:

$$S(\alpha) < (2+p-c)^n$$

or similar (the $c$ can be any positive number including a function of $p$ and $\alpha$). If such a $c$ doesn't exist, then any other (elementary) increasing function that bounds it above as tightly as possible.

Let's take the simple case, $\alpha=\frac 1 2$. Then $S_{X_0}^{-1}(\alpha) = \left[\frac n 2\right]$

In other words we need to show:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{2}]} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j}{(2+p)^n}=O(k^n)$$

for some $k<1$.

But I'm not sure how to prove this.

Note that if $p=0$, this is not the case as we would have for example: $S(.5)=\frac{2^n}{2}$

EDIT: The ultimate goals is to prove that for the $\beta$ in equation (1) below $\beta \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

So, it we can prove:

$$\beta = e^{-(2\lambda+\delta \lambda)t} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac n 2]} {n \choose j}\left(1+\frac{\delta \lambda}{\lambda}\right)^j < e^{-(2\lambda+\delta \lambda)t} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}(2+\frac{\delta \lambda}{\lambda}-\epsilon)^n$$

for some $\epsilon > 0$, that'll do it.

---

Note: Using Wolfram alpha, I get the following (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28n+choose+j%29+%281%2Bp%29%5Ej%2C+j%3D0+to+n%2F2):

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\frac n 2} {n \choose j}(1+p)^j = (2+p)^n-{n \choose {\frac{n}{2}+1}}(1+p)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}{}_2F_1(1,1-\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}+2,-1-p)$$

By sterling's approximation, we get:

$${n \choose \frac{n}{2}} \overset{\sim}{=} \frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Now, if I can find a similar exponential -like approximation for the hypergeometric function..

---

Background:

I have the following expression for the false negative rate of the uniformly most powerful test applied to two Poisson processes when there is a difference in rates ($\lambda_1 = \lambda+\delta \lambda$) and with the false positive rate $\alpha=\frac 1 2$:

$$\beta = \lim_{t \to \infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac n 2]} \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda_1 t}(\lambda_1 t)^j}{j!}\right)\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^{(n-j)}}{(n-j)!}\right)$$

It's pretty clear that this must be $0$. Simplifying we get:

$$\beta =e^{-(2\lambda+\delta \lambda)t} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac n 2]} (\lambda t)^{n-j} (\lambda t + \delta \lambda t)^j \frac{1}{j!(n-j)!}$$

$$ =e^{-(2\lambda+\delta \lambda)t} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac n 2]} {n \choose j}\left(1+\frac{\delta \lambda}{\lambda}\right)^j \tag{1}$$

If the binomial summation inside was not an order of magnitude lower than $(2+\frac{\delta \lambda}{\lambda})^n$, we would get a constant term and not $0$ for the limit. For example, if it were $(2+\frac{\delta \lambda}{\lambda})^n$, we would get $1$.

This makes sense since the dominant terms in $(1+\frac{\delta \lambda}{\lambda})^j$ are getting excluded from the summation. However, not sure how to prove this.

---

EDIT: the following python code demonstrates this result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def binom_partial_sum(n,p=.5):
    b_sum=0
    for j in range(int(n/2)+1):
        b_sum+=comb(n,j)*(1+p)**j
    return b_sum/(2+p)**n
sums = np.array([binom_partial_sum(i,p=0.2) for i in range(11,501,2)])
plt.plot(np.arange(11,501,2),sums)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding but I believe $S(r) \not\sim (2+p-c)^n$ as $(2+p)^n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j+\sum\limits_{j=[\frac{n}{r}]+1}^{n} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j=S(r)+\sum\limits_{j=[\frac{n}{r}]+1}^{n} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j$ and $(1+p)^{[\frac{n}{r}]}$ should be term with the greatest degree in S(r) so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S(r)}{(2+p)^n}\sim\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+p)^{[\frac{n}{r}]}}{(2+p)^n}<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+p)^{[\frac{n}{r}]}}{(1+p)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+p)^{n-[\frac{n}{r}]}}=0$

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. But, there is also a $n \choose [\frac n r]$ term in the numerator of your final limit, no? And for that matter, how can we eliminate the earlier terms lest their binomial coefficients end up making them substantial?

Comment: Sorry I felt it was intuitive and ended reasoning wrongly but I'm glad it helped anyway, so the correct limit should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n \choose [\frac n r]}{(1+p)^{n-[\frac{n}{r}]}}$as I see it should go to zero but to justify it I think one would require to give and asymptotics to [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) (as Stirling gives the asymptotics to n!) the terms that were ignored initially should also go to zero by the same reasoning yet it seems to me it should be an easier way so I will leave it there.

Comment: I had to come back and see if I was not lying to you once again, using the bound for the binomial ${n \choose j}<(\frac{ne}{j})^j$ that appear on the link from before I think the limit should go as follows

Comment: $
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j}{(2+p)^n}
<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j}{(2)^n}
<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]} {n \choose j} (2)^j}{(2)^n}
<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]} (\frac{ne}{j})^j (2)^j}{(2)^n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]}(\frac{ne}{j})^j 2^{j-n}
=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]}\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2e}{j})^j 2^{j\log_2{n}-n}
=0$

Comment: Awesome, thanks! this is 90% of what I was looking for. The other 10% is figuring out what the form of the exponent is for this ratio when $n$ becomes large. You could have easily made this an answer.

Comment: Sorry one more time but I think I have lied to you twice and so I gave you 0% of what you want, the bounds are done fine but don't allow you to conclude that it goes to zero, notice the numerator in $\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]} {n \choose j} (2)^j}{(2)^n}$ belong to the expansion of $(2+1)^n$ so we are comparing something similar to $(\frac{3}{2})^n$ so it's not useful as a bound for the expression

Comment: $1=\frac{S(r)}{(2+p)^{n}}+\frac{\sum\limits_{j=[\frac{n}{r}]+1}^{n} {n \choose j} (1+p)^j}{(2+p)^{n}}$ then if you let r=n/(n-1) you have that $1=\frac{S(r)}{(2+p)^{n}}+\frac{(1+p)^n}{(2+p)^{n}}$ and as $\frac{1+p}{2+p}<1$ then $\frac{S(r)}{(2+p)^n}\to 1$ at first I thought the sum containing the highest degree should be the one to survive but as I see now not necessarily but $r=2$ should be enough to ensure that $\frac{S(r)}{(2+p)^n}\to 0$, sorry for all this wrong comments

Comment: I'm confused about what you want: Do you want constant $c$ that does not depend on $p,\alpha$?  Or do you want $c(\alpha)$ that does not depend on $p$?  Or do you want $c(p,\alpha)$?  (In all these cases I assume you want the $n\to \infty$ limit.)

Comment: Yes, any positive constant will do. It can depend on $p$ and $\alpha$, just needs to be positive. I'm beginning to suspect such a constant might not exist. In that case, any decreasing function for the partial sum divided by $(2+p)^n$ that bounds the whole expression above.

Comment: There are intuitive arguments for why the partial sum divided by $(2+p)^n$ will $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but you need something stronger, i.e. you need to bound the decrease itself asymptotically, ideally as $O(k^n)$ for some $k<1$, but at least as a nice looking function $f(n) \to 0$.  Am I understanding you correctly?  Also, are you opposed to arguments where the large $n$ limit for Binomial is approximated with Gaussian, or would such arguments be not rigorous enough for you?

Comment: First, thanks a lot for all your help so far. My ultimate goal is to show that equation (1) (see edit) becomes $0$ as $t \to \infty$. It is for that purpose that I'm chasing an upper bound for the sum inside that equation so that I can show even something slightly larger goes to $0$ as $t \to \infty$. So, Gaussian approximations are fine as long as they can help make the argument that even slightly larger approximations make that sum go to $0$.

Comment: Note that if the inner summation in equation (1) went from $0$ to $n$, the value would become $1$ regardless of $t$. But since it goes from $0$ to $\frac n 2$, it becomes some decreasing function of $t$ which becomes $0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not too sure what you mean by “survival function” so I’ll replace it with the integer part of $n\alpha$.

First, let’s do the case $\alpha=1/2$ as a warm-up.

$S(1/2)<\sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{n}{k}}(1+p)^{n/2}=(2\sqrt{1+p})^n$.

Now, $2\sqrt{1+p} < 2+p$, as $4(1+p) < 4+4p+p^2$, so we are done.

Now, in the general case $1/2 < \alpha <1$, we only need to find some $k < 2+p$ such that $$S_{\alpha}=\sum_{n/2 < l < n \alpha}{\binom{n}{l}(1+p)^l}=o(k^n).$$

The sum is equal to $(1+p)^nT_n=(1+p)^n\sum_{\beta n < l < n/2}{\binom{n}{l}r^l}$ where $\beta=1-\alpha$ and $r=\frac{1}{1+p}$.

Now, notice that for $0 \leq l < n$, $\binom{n}{l}r^l  \geq \binom{n}{l+1}r^{l+1}$ iff $l>b_n$, where $b_n$ is the smallest integer not below $\frac{rn-1}{1+r}$.

Assume for now $\beta < q:= \frac{r}{1+r}=\frac{1}{2+p}$, and that $n$ is large enough, so that $\beta n < b_n$ (the argument can be adapted to $\beta=q$ without too much trouble but notations and slight changes of indices).

It follows that $\binom{n}{b_n}r^{b_n} \leq T_n \leq n\binom{n}{b_n}r^{b_n}$. By Stirling, if $L(s)=-s\log{s}$ and $q=\frac{r}{1+r}$, it follows $\log{T_n}=n(L(q)+L(1-q)+q\log{r})+O(\log{n})$.

Now, $f=L(q)+L(1-q)+q\log{r}=\log{1+r}$. Therefore, there exists $C > 0$ such that $\frac{(1+r)^n(1+p)^n}{Cn^C} \leq S_{\alpha} \leq Cn^C(1+r)^n(1+p)^n$ with $(1+p)(1+r)=2+p$, so the result is false.

Now, if $\beta > q$, then as above, where $c_n$ is the smallest integer above $n\beta$, $\binom{n}{c_n}r^{c_n} \leq T_n \leq n\binom{n}{c_n}r^{c_n}$.

Thus by Stirling $\log{T_n}=O(\log{n})+n(\beta\log{r}+L(\beta)+L(1-\beta))$.

Now, $C:\beta \longmapsto \beta\log{r}+L(\beta)+L(1-\beta)$ has derivative $\beta \longmapsto \log{r}-\log{\beta}-1+\log{1-\beta}+1=\log{\frac{(1-\beta)r}{\beta}}$, which is negative on $[\beta,q)$, so $C(\beta) < C(q)=\log{1+r}$ and thus, $S_{\alpha}$ is up to a polynomial factor, bounded above by $e^{nC(\beta)}(1+p)^n$, with $e^{C(\beta)}(1+p) < (1+r)(1+p)=2+p$ and it works.

Comment: Sorry, survival function meant the point, $x$ where the $P(X_0>x)=\alpha$.

Comment: Then, to end my argument, it is enough to show that whatever your $\alpha$, the value of the survival function is $n/2+o(n)$. That seems easy enough with the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: Can you give me a rough outline for how we would use the weak law of large numbers here? I have indeed observed this. Even if $\alpha=0.01$, I start getting numbers very close to $n/2$  as it becomes large.

Comment: I haven't understood your answer completely yet, but am awarding the bounty since its going to expire.